# systemd fails to resolve after disconnecting from nordvpn

Tags: systemd, vpn, nordvpn

When I connect to nordvpn, nordlynx creates a network interface and sets its own DNS servers:

```
# nordvpn c
You are connected to Cyprus #43 (cy43.nordvpn.com)!

# systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
     Active: active (running)
...
Aug 22 20:25:19 fedora systemd-resolved[561284]: nordlynx: Bus client set DNS server list to: 103.86.96.100, 103.86.99.100
Aug 22 20:25:19 fedora systemd-resolved[561284]: nordlynx: Bus client set search domain list to: ~.
Aug 22 20:25:19 fedora systemd-resolved[561284]: nordlynx: Bus client set DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade

# systemd-resolve --status
Global
       Protocols: LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub
...
Link 30 (nordlynx)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=allow-downgrade/supported
Current DNS Server: 103.86.96.100
       DNS Servers: 103.86.96.100 103.86.99.100
        DNS Domain: ~.

# ping google.com
PING google.com (192.0.0.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
```

After that, I disconnect and cannot reach anything, including my router:

```
# nordvpn d
# systemd-resolve --status
...
Link 3 (wlp4s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

# nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 20600

# dig 192.168.1.1
; <<>> DiG 9.16.27-RH <<>> 192.168.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

It doesn't happen everytime, but only if nordvpn connection is left untouched for a long time (4 hours and more). The only solution I have found is system reboot.

Why does it happen? Are there any other solutions?
Also, I'll be thankful for troubleshooting tips.